# IGDB by Twitch API hourly/minutely rate limit?

Tags: twitch-api

I'm running queries against the IGDB API, and cannot find any documentation on how many requests/minute am I allowed to send via their free plan. There is a limit of 5 requests/minute against their api_status endpoint- but I cannot find any information for other endpoints like games. I'm aware of the 50,000 requests/month, but I'm trying to figure out whether there is a request limit per minute/hour as well, or I can just send as many requests as I want until I run out of requests?

Answer (score 2):

Rate Limits ([https://api-docs.igdb.com/#rate-limits][1])

> There is a rate limit of 4 requests per second. If you go over this
> limit you will receive a response with status code 429 Too Many
> Requests.
>
> You are able to have up to 8 open requests at any moment in time. This
> can occur if requests take longer than 1 second to respond when
> multiple requests are being made.

Answer (score -1):

I heard back from support- there's no rate limit over small time intervals.